# How can I replace my txt file with an array?

Tags: c#

I made a array out of a txt file and now i want to replace the array in this txt file (replace like in update).
becouse i edited the array, and now i want to replace the txt file again , i hope its possible and i hope its possible with breaklines.

```
string[] linesa = File.ReadLines("file1.txt").ToArray();
```

this is the line where i make a array of my txt.

```
number = Array.IndexOf(linesa, commonElement);           
number = number + 1;    
email  = linesa[number];
linesa[number] = "";
number = number - 1;
linesa[number] = "";
```

this is the edit i made and now i want to put it back in the txt file this is where i have alot of problems with.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`WriteAllLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. It will replace the contents of the file if the file exists.

```
File.WriteAllLines("file1.txt", linesa);
```

Comment: i tried this but i get an error i got cannot convert from string[] to string wich seems so weird

Comment: @JordyHuijgens check your arguments order. first argument is path, the other one is array.

Comment: nope i didnt put them in the wrong order and it just keeps giving this problem

Comment: fixed : i had WriteAllText -.-